# SQL Server Link Server to Google BigQuery is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have created a Link Server to Google BigQuery. Test connection to this gets successful but when I expand Catalog to view tables or views i get below error.

Steps Followed:
1- Installed and Configured ODBC Driver for BigQuery. ( Successful)
2 - Created Link Server
Link Server Configuration :
[image]

[image: Error Message]

Tried MSDASQL Setting changes under providers as well. Check , uncheck Allow inprocess. but that doesnt work. Test Connection is Successful with UnCheck Allow Inprocess setting fail otherwise. but overall this is not working.

Answer (score -1):

There are optional metadata APIs in both OleDb and ODBC.  If these aren't implemented by the drive or don't work together as expected you won't be able to browse metadata over the linked server.

You may still be able to run queries using OPENQUERY or even with four-part names.

However it is *highly discouraged* to use obscure 3rd-party drivers for linked server.  It can seriously impact the stability and uptime of your SQL Server.  Much better is to use an SSIS package to access the data source.

If you want you can use the SSIS [Data Streaming Destination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/data-streaming-destination?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=The%20Data%20Streaming%20Destination%20is%20a%20SQL%20Server,to%20display%20data%20returned%20by%20the%20SSIS%20package.) to enable you to "Select *" from an SSIS package, much the way you would in Linked Server, but safer.